# Partial differential Equation over characteristic p

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, finite-fields, characteristic-p

I want some references on partial differential equations over characteristic $p$. If we have a first order partial differential equation, how can we check whether there exists polynomials or rational functions over characteristic $p$ , which satisfies the equation?